# How do I fake IO input when testing with ExUnit?

Tags: testing, functional-programming, elixir, ex-unit

I have an Elixir program I'd like to test which gets input from the user via `IO.gets` several times. How would I go about faking this input in a test?

Note: I would like to return a different value for each `IO.gets`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The preferred way to do it is to split your code into pure (no side effects) and impure (does the io). So if your code looks like this:

```
IO.gets
...
...
...
IO.gets
...
...
```

try to extract the parts between IO.gets into functions that you can test in isolation from `IO.gets`:

```
def fun_to_test do
  input1 = IO.gets
  fun1(input1)
  input2 = IO.gets
  fun2(input2)
end
```

and then you can test the functions in isolation. This isn't always the best thing to do, especially if the impure parts are deep inside `if`, `case` or `cond` statements.

The alternative is to pass the `IO` as an explicit dependency:

```
def fun_to_test(io \\ IO) do
  io.gets
  ...
  ...
  ...
  io.gets
  ...
  ...
end
```

This way you can use it from you production code without any modification, but in your test you can pass it some different module `fun_to_test(FakeIO)`. If the prompts are different you can just pattern match on the `gets` argument.

```
defmodule FakeIO do
  def gets("prompt1"), do: "value1"
  def gets("prompt2"), do: "value2"
end
```

If they are always the same you need to keep the state of how many times the `gets` was called:

```
defmodule FakeIO do
  def start_link do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> 1 end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def gets(_prompt) do
    times_called = Agent.get_and_update(__MODULE__, fn state ->
      {state, state + 1}
    end)
    case times_called do
      1 -> "value1"
      2 -> "value2"
    end
  end
end
```

This last implementation is a fully working mock with its internal state. You need to call `FakeIO.start_link` before using it in the test. If this is what you need to do in many places you may consider some mocking library, but as you can see - this isn't too complicated. To make the `FakeIO` even better you can print the prompt. I skipped this detail here.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Found the FakeIO solution in the accepted answer very helpful. Wished to add another clear example, and also point out delegation from FakeIO to the real IO when needed*

Here, I have a simple requirement to write an App that does a little IO, reading a name from STDIN and replying on STDOUT.

**Example Output**

> What is your name? Elixir
>
> Hello, Elixir, nice to meet you!

Below is the "app", a single module called `Ex1`:

```
defmodule Ex1 do

  def sayHello(io \\ IO) do
    "What is your name? "
    |> input(io)
    |> reply
    |> output(io)
  end

  def input(message, io \\ IO) do
    io.gets(message) |> String.trim
  end

  def reply(name) do
   "Hello, #{name}, nice to meet you!"
  end

  def output(message, io \\ IO) do
    io.puts(message)
  end

end
```

And associated tests:

```
defmodule FakeIO do
  defdelegate puts(message), to: IO
  def gets("What is your name? "), do: "Elixir "
  def gets(value), do: raise ArgumentError, message: "invalid argument #{value}"
end

defmodule Ex1Test do
  use ExUnit.Case
  import ExUnit.CaptureIO
  doctest Ex1

  @tag runnable: true
  test "input" do
    assert Ex1.input("What is your name? ", FakeIO) == "Elixir"
  end

  @tag runnable: true
  test "reply" do
    assert Ex1.reply("Elixir") == "Hello, Elixir, nice to meet you!"
  end

  @tag runnable: true
  test "output" do
    assert capture_io(fn ->
      Ex1.output("Hello, Elixir, nice to meet you!", FakeIO)
    end) == "Hello, Elixir, nice to meet you!\n"
  end

  @tag runnable: true
  test "sayHello" do
    assert capture_io(fn ->
      Ex1.sayHello(FakeIO)
    end) == "Hello, Elixir, nice to meet you!\n"
  end

end
```

The interesting part is the usage of `FakeIO` in conjunction with parameter pattern matching and `defdelegate` to delegate to the real `IO.puts` call. There is a "catchall" pattern on `gets` to raise an ArgumentError if anything other than the expected gets param is passed to FakeIO.

```
 defmodule FakeIO do
   defdelegate puts(message), to: IO
   def gets("What is your name? "), do: "Elixir "
   def gets(value), do: raise ArgumentError, message: "invalid argument #{value}"
 end
```

Anyhow, hope this offers some insights in regards to FakeIO usage.