# Testing recursive IO prompt in Elixir/Erlang

Tags: recursion, io, erlang, elixir, ex-unit

I have a function `confirm`, which reads IO input, and depending by input, if it's `y` (yes) or `n` (no), it returns `true/false`, otherwise it calls `confirm` again, until any expected `y` or `n` is entered.

```
@spec confirm(binary) :: boolean
def confirm(question) do
  answer = question |> IO.gets() |> String.trim() |> String.downcase()

  case(answer) do
    "y" -> true
    "n" -> false
    _ -> confirm(question)
  end
end
```

To test `y` and `n` cases it's easy:

`assert capture_io([input: "y"], fn -> confirm("Question") end) == "Question"`

But I have no idea how to capture IO multiple times to test recursive case, let's say if at first input is "invalid" and then "y". Does elixir has any way to test IO functions like this? Or maybe do you have some suggestions how I could rewrite function to test it easier?

Original question https://elixirforum.com/t/testing-recursive-io-prompt/3715

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This answer / example may also help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46630883/1882064

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but what about just using newline characters?

```
assert capture_io([input: "foo\nbar\ny"], fn -> confirm("Question") end) == "Question"
```